# How to get total number

Tags: python, django, api, model, frameworks

How to get the total number of loved clicked? My attempt is below, but it is not working.

This is my model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    reviewer    = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='review', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='review', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date_time   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment     = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    rating      = models.CharField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, max_length=150)
    loved       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is my view:

```
class ListReviewAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
      queryset = Review.objects.filter(loved="True").count()
      serializer_class = ReviewSerializers
```

The serializers

```
class ReviewSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Review
    fields = ['product', 'comment', 'rating', 'loved', 'date_time', 'reviewer']
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: It makes no sense that this is a `queryset`... You use a `ListAPIView`, so this is to *list* the `Review`s...

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just override get method to simplify what you want to do?

```py
class GetReviewRate(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        count = Review.objects.filter(loved=True).count()
        return Response({'loved_count': count})
```

Also Boolean values are `False/True`, not `"False"/"True"`, they're not strings. Remember about that.